# Как правильно сделать цикл while на Python и уместен ли он тут

Tags: python

Я написал скрипт для сбора логов СХД NetApp Е5600, внешние данные забираются из Excel файла, а именно: Имя, Rack, SN. Oн работает,но теперь я занимаюсь тюнингом, и не понимаю как  при не правильном вводе от пользователя, говорить ему что он ошибся и попытаться снова. Пробовал "While true", но пока успешного результата не добился. Ниже приведена часть кода которая работает, какие поправки мне нужно внести для осуществления задуманного ?

```
sanName = input('Enter the name of storage system in 07-06 format:
for row in ws.rows:
   for cell in row:
            if cell.value == sanName:
                storage_name = ws.cell(row=cell.row, column=1).value
                storage_rack = ws.cell(row=cell.row, column=2).value
                storage_unit = ws.cell(row=cell.row, column=5).value
```

Comment: Какой ввод считается правильным, а какой нет? При правильном вводе делаете `break` для выхода из цикла. `input` должен быть внутри "вечного цикла" `while True:`

Comment: Нынешний код который я использую описан выше, и так же в строке "sanName = input('Enter the name of storage system in 07-06 format" описано в каком виде вводить параметры.

Comment: Ещё раз. Что такое "правильный ввод от пользователя"? Это когда у вас срабатывает `if cell.value == sanName:`? Или как вы определяете правильный ввод?

Comment: Вы правы, когда выполняется cell.value == sanName - этот является правильным вводом

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Каркас "вечного цикла" примерно следующий:

```
while True:
    something = input()
    if <проверка, что с вводом всё хорошо>:
        break
```

В вашем случае у вас `if` находится внутри двух циклов `for` поэтому так не получится, `break` прервёт только самый внутренний цикл. Рекомендую вынести весь этот код в отдельную функцию и при успешной проверке возвращаться из функции через `return`. Можно и по-другому - делать флаг, выставлять его, проверять внутри обоих `for` и делать `break`, но это будет больше кода и код будет более запутанный.

```
def check_input():
    while True:
        something = input()
        for ...
            if <убедились, что ввод был правильный>:
                return
```

Comment: Спасибо,это помогло. Я добился того чего хотел!